osgi : cannot obtain the bundle with method getService
Im using jdk22 , osgi 8.0.0 and apache felix 7.0.5
I have a jar with just one Interface called
public interface Person{

    public void sayHi();
}

and I use it in two proyects, one of them where I have the Activator Class (bundle), here I created a service and registered through BundleContext
public class Main implements BundleActivator {

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("Hello world.");


        Hashtable<String,String> map = new Hashtable<>();
        map.put("key","value");
        ctx.registerService(
                Person.class,
                new PersonImpl(),
                map );


    }
    
    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) {
    }
}

and Finally I have the proyect where comsume the bundle, here I created the BundleContext, installed and start the bundle, my problem happens because i can see the service when Iterate over getRegisteredServices() method
            System.out.println(bundle.getRegisteredServices());
            for(ServiceReference serviceReference: bundle.getRegisteredServices()) {
                System.out.println(serviceReference); //print a value
            }

But when i try to get the ServiceReference it return me null
context.getServiceReference(Person.class); // its return me null

what can i doing wrong ?
get the service reference from bundleContext.getServiceReference

was my error, exists two context, one is the context from the framework and the other is the context of Bundle
Felix felix = new Felix(config);
felix.start();
BundleContext context = felix.getBundleContext();

and the other is the context of the bundle
ServiceReference<Person> perdonRef =  bundle.getBundleContext().getServiceReference(Person.class);
Person person = bundle.getBundleContext().getService(saludosRef);

